# How to append div next to input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field which I created like this.

```
var inputVal = document.createElement("input");

inputVal.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
inputChek.onchange = select;
inputChek.setAttribute("value", title);

//inputChek.after(sortDiv);
docClass.prepend(inputChek);
docClass.append(newDiv);
```

I want to add the div with arrow image just after the text but it is not apparing. div is getting creating but it is going down.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

newDiv.setAttribute("class", "Arrow");
//sortDiv.style.display = ' transform: rotate(45deg), webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);'*/
newDiv.setAttribute("onclick",'divClick("title")');
newDiv.style.background = "red";
newDiv.style.width = "10px";
newDiv.style.height = "10px";
```

Here is the image.

I want to add after text. [image]
Any solution for this.

Comment: if you want to add something inline, why do you use a div (== a block element) and not a span?

Comment: Shall I need to use `span` here

Comment: Yes, span has an inline display while div has a block display (css wise).
Change your code: var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
 => var newSpan = document.createElement("span"); and update the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic example how to add `div` element after input,
you can modify (and style) it as you wish:

```js
var root = document.getElementById("root"),
    checkbox = document.createElement("input"),
    block = document.createElement("div");

checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.value = "title";

block.className = "arrow";
block.setAttribute("onclick",'divClick("title")');
block.style.background = "red";
block.style.display = "inline-block";
block.style.width = "36px";
block.style.height = "12px";

root.appendChild(checkbox);
root.appendChild(block);

function divClick( text ){
  console.log('you had just clicked the ' + text );
}
```

```html
<div id="root" class="form-group"></div>
```